# Need more info with helicon isapi and regex rule

Tags: regex, helicontech

I am working on a helicon rule and tried various combinations but they didn't work

I want the following URL to be resolved.

It can be this

```
www.test.com/myownpages/
```

or

```
www.test.com/myownpages
www.test.com/myownpages/?value1=test2&value2=test2
```

it should be resolved to

```
$1/test.aspx  [NC]
```

If anyone gives something after myownpages, it shouldn't work

```
www.test.com/myownpages/test (This shouldn't work)
```

It tried the below so far

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\/\myownpages\/)(.*)(\?)?(.+)?$ $1/test.aspx [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with these rewrite rules, but maybe I can help with the regex. As I read it, you want to match any string ending with "/myownpages", "/myownpages/", or "/myownpages/?anything" and capture the part before that.
I'd use

```
^(.*)/myownpages(/([?].+)?)?$
```

to get this. [See it in action at RegExr.](http://regexr.com?2ursn) If you need to escape the forward slashes, it becomes.

```
^(.*)\/myownpages(\/([?].+)?)?$
```

Note that this will not preserve the values in the query string; it will rewrite `www.test.com/myownpages/?value1=test2&value2=test2` to `www.test.com/test.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want rewrite (NOT redirect) from /myownpages --> /myownpages/test.aspx, try using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule myownpages/?$ /myownpages/test.aspx [NC,QSA,L]
```

QSA-flag appends the query string to the source path automatically.